# genetic algorithm matlab starting point

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

I have a function of the following form I am trying to minimize

```
q = (y - (x(1)*(x(3) - (x(3)-1)*(exp(-x(2)*z)))))^2
```

I have values for `y` and `z`, I'm trying to estimate `x` using Genetic algorithm.

How and where do I specify my starting guess for `x` ?

For example, I would like the GA to start the optimization using `[0.1, 1, 10]` as an initial guess for `x`. Where would I specify this in GA toolbox in matlab ?

I'm a little confused between Initial Range and Initial Scores as the place where I specify my initial guess (first time using GA).

Comment: This is a weird question.. `x = [0.1, 1, 10]` `<---` Add this line before `q = .... `

Comment: You have to consider that for genetic algorithms, there is no initial *point* where the search commences but rather an initial *population*. By default `ga` creates this itself, using a uniform distribution. You can excercise some control over it, see https://de.mathworks.com/help/gads/genetic-algorithm-options.html#f14223 for details.

Comment: Random :) And GA not start at exactly one point, you have population, so there will be more start points. Some will be betters than others and this fact creates preference and evolution may start.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot. Just a last question, what's the difference between Initial Range and Initial Score in MATLAB GA toolbox ?

Comment: From the documentation: "Initial range (InitialPopulationRange) specifies the range of the vectors in the initial population that is generated", this should be pretty clear. As for scores, I understand it as a measure of the fitness of your population (high scores means good candidates that are likely to survive, low scores are likely to die). I wouldn't know why you should but it seems you can specify the scores of your initial population.

Comment: So the initial range is just the bounds for initial vectors generated, subsequent vectors generated may or may not adhere to the specified initial range. Have I got that part right ?. Thanks for the replies, appreciate it.